# glBlitFramebuffer Invalid Operation

Tags: c++, opengl, render, blit

I've been messing around with framebuffers and render to texture and I came across the need to blit them. Again on some machines I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` right after the `glBlitFramebuffer` call. Each texture bound to the framebuffer is setup the exact same way, all the same size and parameters. Also, when I try to blit one entire texture (previously succesfully rendered to) to another framebuffer, only the destination 'rectangle' to write in is smaller than the rectangle to read from (e.g. when I want to blit it to a quarter of the screen), it throws a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` too.

**EDIT:** *Actually it always throws the error whenever the rectangles to read from and draw to have a different size, so I can't blit to a texture of a different size, or the same size but a different sized 'render to' area...?*

Everytime I blit to a manually generated framebuffer the status is checked through `glCheckFramebufferStatus` and it always returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

*-BIGGEST SNIP EVER-, see below for shorter 'source code', obviously a couple C++ errors and not complete, but its only for the GL calls*

The OpenGL error occurs when I call the last method of the viewport (Viewport::blit) with the screen framebuffer as target (by passing NULL). It first sets the read buffer of its own framebuffer (the draw buffers were already set) and then it calls RenderTarget::blit which calls `glBlitFramebuffer`. In the blit method it binds both buffers, and you can see it calls `glCheckFramebufferStatus` there which does not return an error.

I've been reading [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer) over and over but I can't seem to find the error that causes it. When I blit the color buffer I use `GL_LINEAR`, otherwise I use `GL_NEAREST` All color buffers use `GL_RGB32F` as internal format and the depth buffer (which I never blit) uses `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`

**EDIT, a shorter example, just took all the GL calls and filled the params I used**

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, _GL_Framebuffer);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + index);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// OpenGL error check, does not return an error

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, _GL_Framebuffer);
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    // Some error checking, fortunately status always turns out to be complete
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, target, (target == GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ? GL_LINEAR : GL_NEAREST);

// If the source/destination read/draw rectangles are different in size, GL_INVALID_OPERATION is cought here
```

And the Framebuffer/Texture creation:

```
glGenFramebuffer(1, &_GL_Framebuffer);

glGenTextures(1, &_GL_ZBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _GL_ZBuffer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _GL_Framebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT + 0, _GL_ZBuffer, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

int writeIndices[BUFFER_COUNT];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i)
{
    writeIndices[i] = i;

    glGenTextures(1, &_GL_Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _GL_Texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _GL_Framebuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, _GL_Texture, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // In the actual code each texture is obviously saved in an object
}

GLenum *enums = new GLenum[BUFFER_COUNT];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < BUFFER_COUNT; ++i)
{
    // Get index and validate
    int index = *(indices + i); // indices = writeIndices
    if(index < 0 || index >= maxAttachments)
    {
        delete[] enums;
        return false;
    }

    // Set index
    enums[i] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + index;
}

// Set indices
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, _GL_Framebuffer);
glDrawBuffers(BUFFER_COUNT, enums);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

delete[] enums;

// OpenGL error check, no errors
```

Comment: Is any of your FBO's multisampled?

Comment: Oo about that, I never set any parameters concerning multisampling, I don't know how FBOs handle that themselves, but I'd assume they currently follow default behavior. I'd appreciate a hint in the right direction about how to set a FBO's multisampling behavior xD

Also note it does succesfully blit if the draw/read rectangles are equal, it only throws the error when they're not, or on some laptops (the laptops SHOULD support at lest OpenGL 3.2).

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FBO) and [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer). It contains other possible causes also, because it's hard to guess here. Your example is way too long, can't you try to reproduce it in a line or 20?

Comment: Ok I've gone through each call and took out all OpenGL calls, see the bottom of the question for the actual blitting code and the framebuffer/texture creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some careful reading I found out the difference in multisampling was the problem. The 'main' FBO was setup by SFML, so by simply setting the anti aliasing level on startup to 0 the problem was *partially* solved.

It now blits if the draw/read rectangles are unequal in size, but it keeps crashing on some machines where it is SUPPOSED to work.

Comment: How old are the drivers on those machines? There are some old drivers on which FBO's tend to misbehave (allthough, these are very old). edit: the trick is, if your src framebuffer is multisampled, you should be able to draw to a non-sampled fbo, but only one of equal size is guaranteed to work iirc. So maybe, on those platforms the default framebuffer is still multisampled. Bliting with unequal sizes but the same sample rate should work without limitations.